# a-frame : how to make the hands follow the camera?

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I'm starting to learn aframe and want to use it with an Oculus Quest 2. I have the hands displayed and I'm trying to move around the VR world but when I move the hands don't move ... how to make the hands follow the camera?
thanks

This is my code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/v6.1.0/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>

    <script>


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-entity id="rig" movement-controls position="0 0 0">
            <a-entity camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true"></a-entity>
        </a-entity>

        <a-entity id="leftHand" hand-controls="hand: left; handModelStyle: lowPoly; color: #ffcccc"></a-entity>
        <a-entity id="rightHand" hand-controls="hand: right; handModelStyle: lowPoly; color: #ffcccc"></a-entity>
                                


      <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
      <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found ...

At the beginning I put the controllers in the camera ... but I had to put them in #rig

```
<a-entity id="rig" movement-controls position="0 0 0">
   <a-entity camera position="0 0 0" look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true"></a-entity>

    <a-entity id="leftHand" hand-controls="hand: left; handModelStyle: lowPoly;"></a-entity>
    <a-entity id="rightHand" hand-controls="hand: right; handModelStyle: lowPoly;"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: Please accept it as "correct answer" when You can :+1: